# Ubuntu Server 12.04: apt-get won't install vsftpd (Package is not available, but is referred by another)

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt, ftp

When I try to install VSFTPD to my Ubuntu Server 12.04 instance by the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install vsftpd
```

I get the following error:

```
Package vsftpd is not available, but is referred by another package.
```

Does it mean I am using wrong alias? Or is there another way to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that I had to try different repos for apt-get.

So I have edited Ubuntu Main Repos section in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and changed server addresses to different ones. I also have included universe and multiverse repos.

From these:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
```

To these:

```
deb http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
```

Then after running sudo apt-get update, I was be able to install vsftpd package.